# What does /** ..... */ mean

Tags: c

I was looking through some C codes and libraries for AVR micro-controllers and I saw this odd commenting type(`/** code */`)

What is the difference between:

```
/**
some line of code
*/
```

and

```
/*
some line of code
*/
```

Comment: Really, why do you think there is a difference?

Comment: Read some basics of C programming.

Comment: *What is the difference ...?* One `*` character?

Comment: @AndrewHenle or, _one irrelevant character?_

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/comment

Comment: *Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `/*` introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the characters `*/` that terminate it* -(as per standard) So if you put even multiple `*` nothing significant there. So the C language itself won't distinguish them. But yes any other tool or anything that you might use apart from it - can give it other meaning. The best way to go about it is to check the manual if any which mentions of this things. They will if there is.

Comment: @machine_1 Maybe it's irrelevant, maybe not.  But literally, that's the only difference.

Comment: This document refers to the first example as "JavaDoc style" https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html#docstructure

Comment: Some coders will use `/********************` and `********************/` to prettify the code, with documentation between them.

Answer (score 7):

This type of comment in C is used for Doxygen documentation. Doxygen is very useful if you want to generate documentation directly written in your code. If you put such a block of comment just before a function for instance, Doxygen can link what you write as a comment to the function.

Comment: However if you don't use Doxygen, this has no effect, the second `*` is just a part of your comment.